# How to use where inside a find for complex search queries?

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

I have a model of product which contains a list, and I need to find the product and filter it according to the language.

```
return Collection.Find(p => p.ProductValues.Where(pv => pv.Lang == lang)).toList();
```

And the error I am getting is

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TestMongodb.Entities.ProductValue>' to 'bool'
```

My models are

```
 public class Product : BaseEntity
    {
        public Product(string price, string date, List<ProductValue> value) =>
            (Price, Date, ProductValues) = (price, date, value);

        public string Price { get; set; }

        public string Date { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("value")]
        public List<ProductValue> ProductValues { get; set; }
    }
```

and

```
public class ProductValue
    {
        public ProductValue(string lang, string name, string description) =>
           (Lang, Name, Description) = (lang, name, description);

        [BsonElement("lang")]
        public string Lang { get; }

        [BsonElement("name")]
        public string Name { get; }

        [BsonElement("description")]
        public string Description { get; }
    }
```

Comment: I don't fully understand your query. `Find` returns the first single instance that matches. Why are you trying to call `ToList` on a single instance?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `Where()`, use `Any()`,

```
return Collection.Find(p => p.ProductValues.Any(pv => pv.Lang == lang));
```

---

Why `Any()` over `Where()`?

- `Where(<predicate>)` clause is used to filter-out based on predicate passed to it. It return set of new filtered records instead of `true/false` values.

`Any(<predicate>)` : `Any()` returns `true/false` if predicate satisfies the condition. `

Now, Find returns document based on the condition which returns boolean true, instead of new list. This is the reason we used `Any()` instead of `Where()`

Comment: This does not work  i still get multiple languages, i need to filter the list, and get only the correct language. Example: "productValues": [
      {
        "lang": "ru",
        "name": "zzzz",
        "description": "string"
      },
      {
        "lang": "en",
        "name": "xxxx",
        "description": "string"
      }
    ],

Comment: Can you please provide what is input and what output you are expecting

Comment: @AzadSamedov, what do you mean by correct language, which is the correct language here?